# imageview with no white background

Tags: android

I have a transparent image and when I add in my imageview it appears like this

[image: SNAP]

but I want to remove the white background of the image . I need only the boy in theimage to be show and remove the white background

is there any way I can do it ???
i ise everything but cant remove this background 
this my my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="110dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="9dp"
app:cardElevation="10dp"
android:id="@+id/cardview"
android:background="@null" >

  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/category_item"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@null" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show imageview in android studio without white background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57609754/show-imageview-in-android-studio-without-white-background)

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working, will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: It is working with android:background="@null" , just set a sorce android:src

Comment: Use .png or .svg + use src="your image" + delete this "android:background="@null" " from your code

Answer (score 0):

Use [paint.net](https://www.getpaint.net) to edit images.

[image]

Save the image and the white background is removed.

Comment: @TripleSAcademy You have to add android:background="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: i try this but no changes

Comment: @TripleSAcademy Do you use a white background in your whole app?

Comment: jakob .. no i used just a background on this fragment but where can i see if there is any background for the whole project ?

Comment: @TripleSAcademy Join this room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198422/whitebackground

Comment: i cant sorry .. this error shown " You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq."

Comment: @TripleSAcademy Ok, try to set a black backround to your CardView (#000)

Comment: @TripleSAcademy and you set the background of your ImageView transparent?

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain the background is truly transparent in the image? If it isn't you can try to edit it first by adding it to Photoshop and moving the black pixels to a new layer with a transparent background. Or you can try any of the .svg converter websites which can render simple images as .svg which you can download as a .png.

If that doesn't work there seems to be a similar question answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6873336/9530685

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty obvious but I said maybe you forgot

do you sure your image is PNG!!!?

for no background image you must use png format